# (Vue.js) Should I erase semicolon at an API? or ignore eslint?

Tags: api, vue.js, eslint

After I use API at my program, lots of errors/warnings appear because of eslint. Eslint told me to erase semicolon at API. But I'm not sure it's okay to erase semicolon at the API. So I just want to ignore eslint. I write this code between template and script.

`/* eslint-disable */`

But It didn't work, I don't know why.
So this is my question. Can you kindly answer to these questions? Thank you.

1. Is it okay to erase semicolon at the API?
2. Why /* eslint-disable */ didn't work?

A Whole code is at the bottom.

```
<template>
<div>
    <div class="searchAroundMe">
    <form action="search.php" method="post">
        <input class="btn_text" type="text">
        <input class="btn_submit" type="submit" value="SEARCH">
    </form>
    </div>
    <h1 class="header2"></h1>

    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
</div>
</template>
/* eslint-disable */
<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    window.kakao && window.kakao.maps
      ? this.initMap()
      : this.addKakaoMapScript();
  },
  methods: {
    addKakaoMapScript() {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      /* global kakao */
      script.onload = () => kakao.maps.load(this.initMap);
      script.src =
        "http://dapi.kakao.com/v2/maps/sdk.js?autoload=false&appkey=*APPKEY*";
      document.head.appendChild(script);
    },
    initMap() {
      var container = document.getElementById("map");
      var options = {
        center: new kakao.maps.LatLng(33.450701, 126.570667),
        level: 3
      };

      var map = new kakao.maps.Map(container, options);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your eslint-disable command is a JavaScript comment, but you have written it in HTML code (after a template element and before a script element, so it is treated as plaintext). It would need to be within the `<script>...</script>` tags for it to get recognized.

Semi-colons are not required at the end of statements in JavaScript, so your eslint configuration may expect them to be omitted. You can change the configuration settings to always require them if that is what your project prefers.